# How to use PDFBox to create a link that goes to *previous view*?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox, acrobat

By using PDFBox, it is easy to create a link that goes a particular page or page view by using `PDPageDestination`.  For example, the following code will make a link that goes to page 9:

```
PDAnnotationLink link         = new PDAnnotationLink();
PDPageDestination destination = new PDPageFitWidthDestination();
PDActionGoTo action           = new PDActionGoTo();

destination.setPage(document.getPage(9));
action.setDestination(destination);
link.setAction(action);
```

**Problem:**

Instead of going to a particular page, I would like to go to the previous **view**.

For example, suppose in a PDF file, each of P.1 and P.2 has a link that goes to P. 9.  Now I would like to put on P. 9 a link that goes back to where the user started.

If the user started out at P.1 and clicked the link to P.9, he arrives at P.9.  When he clicks the link on P. 9, he will go back to P.1, where he came from.  But If he started out at P.2, then the link at P.9 will go back to P.2 instead.

***Question:   How do I achieve this with PDFBox?***

FYI, with Adobe Acrobat, this can be achieved by adding an "execute a menu item" action to a link, and then choosing "Previous View" as the menu item, as shown in this screenshot:

[Link to Acrobat screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13566649/sample.jpg)

Comment: I found an implementation note in the PDF spec "Acrobat viewers extend the list of named actions in Table 8.61 to include most of the menu item names available in the viewer." So one would need to get such a PDF file, find the name, and use that name as destination.

Comment: Many thanks Tilman.  Sorry I'm new to PDFBox.  May I have some guidance on how to find the name and use that name as destination?

Comment: Open the PDF file you created in an editor like NOTEPAD++, search if you find something like "prev", "menu", "view", hopefully that will be it. Or look at it with PDFDebugger (a command line application of PDFBox). Or upload a non confidential file with that feature at a public place and I'll have a look at it to find that name.

Comment: I opened my PDF file with a text editor and found the following.  This is exactly the coordinate of the link that I created by Acrobat.  But I'm not sure what /H, /P, /BS or /A means.  How do I use such information to reproduce such a link with PDFBox?
<<
/Type /Annot
/Subtype /Link
/Rect [0.0 0.0 100.0 100.0]
/H /P
/BS 1049 0 R
/A 1050 0 R
>>

Comment: The meaning can be found in the PDF spec in the segment [Additional entries specific to a link annotation](http://www.verypdf.com/document/pdf-format-reference/pg_0622.htm). Now it would be interesting whats at 1050 0 o.

Comment: @Tilman You're very helpful indeed.  It turns out that 1050 0 is <</N /GoBack /S /Named>>.  I believe, as you mentioned, it is a "named action" as specified by PDF spec.  I further think that this is not a "named destination".  My question now is:  How to set a named action to a PDAction object in PDFBox?  Which subclass should I use (PDActionGoTo, PDActionLaunch, PDActionRemoteGoTo or PDActionURI), or is it something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the guidance of Tilman, I managed to solve my own problem.

I cannot find a PDAction subclass that gives me the capability to add a "named action", so I created my own subclass, "PDActionNamed":

```
class PDActionNamed extends PDAction {

    public static final String SUB_TYPE = "Named";    

    public PDActionNamed() {
        super();
        setSubType( SUB_TYPE );
    }

    public void setN( String s ) {
        action.setName( "N", s );
    }
}
```

To use the subclass,

```
PDAnnotationLink link   = new PDAnnotationLink(); 
PDActionNamed action = new PDActionNamed ();
action.setN("GoBack");    // this is one of Acrobat's default named action
link.setAction(action);
```

It seems to work even on non-Javascript-supported PDF readers (e.g. SumatraPDF).

Comment: +1 Just what I was thinking after finding nothing. (Very embarassing! Amusingly, PDFBox preflight does support named actions) I'll create a JIRA issue to add something similar into our code.

Comment: I've created https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-2620 . Btw your solution has one possible flaw, I believe that the named action won't exist if you load the PDF with PDFBox, e.g. for manipulating an existing file and saving it. To fix this, one must change PDActionFactory to include the new element. But this shouldn't be a problem as long as you're only creating PDF files.

Comment: Done. You can find a snapshot in a few hours here: https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox/1.8.9-SNAPSHOT/ Please test it to see that it works as good as your solution already does. If it doesn't work properly, write in the JIRA issue or contact me directly (tilman at snafu dot de).

Comment: I've tried using the PDActionNamed class in the snapshot.  It works perfectly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you're talking about is a viewer dependant action; I don't think there is a way to do this generically but there should be ways to do this in Adobe Acrobat / Adobe Reader.

One such way is to insert a link that triggers an Action. The action could be a Javascript action and the Javascript could be relatively simple as the Acrobat Javascript API contains an "app" method called "goBack".

So, insert a link as you're doing right now. Insert not a GoTo action but a Javascript action. And set the Javascript to: "app.goBack()".

This should work in Acrobat (they have a similar example with a button form field in the Acrobat Javascript API reference. The question is whether it will work in other viewers as well and thus whether it will fulfil your business case.

Comment: Thanks David.Is Acrobat JavaScript is the only way to implemented this?  I tried to produce the link with Acobat, and then use SumatraPDF - a PDF reader that specifically does NOT support JavaScript - to open the resulting file.  And yet the link works fine with SumatraPDF.

Comment: @BrianL. this suggests that Acrobat does it without JS.

Comment: It will probably depend on the viewer really, but as Tilman says, that indicates that Acrobat does something else. Looking at the original comment on your question from Tilman, it probably means that Acrobat extended the names and that SumatraPDF implemented those (non standard names). Whether viewers will support those custom names and/or Javascript is really something you'd have to investigate. That's why I stressed the "not generically" bit in my answer.