# How to use PDFBox to create a link i can click to go to another page in the same document

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am trying to use PDFBox to create a link i can click to go to another page in the same document.

From this question ([How to use PDFBox to create a link that goes to *previous view*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28060866/how-to-use-pdfbox-to-create-a-link-that-goes-to-previous-view)) I see that this should be easy to do, but when i try to do it I get this error:  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Destination of a GoTo action must be a page dictionary object

I am using this code:

```
//Loading an existing document consisting of 3 empty pages.
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Student\\Documents\\MyPDF\\Test_doc.pdf");
    PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file);
    PDPage page = document.getPage(1);

    PDAnnotationLink link         = new PDAnnotationLink();
    PDPageDestination destination = new PDPageFitWidthDestination();
    PDActionGoTo action           = new PDActionGoTo();

    destination.setPageNumber(2);
    action.setDestination(destination);
    link.setAction(action);
    link.setPage(page);
```

I am using PDFBox 2.0.13, can anyone give me some guidance on what I'm doing wrong?

Appreciate all answers.

Comment: See also the AddAnnotation.java example in the source code download. And update to 2.0.14.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, for a local link (*"a link i can click to go to another page in the same document"*), `destination.setPageNumber` is the wrong method to use, cf. its JavaDocs:

```
/**
 * Set the page number for a remote destination. For an internal destination, call 
 * {@link #setPage(PDPage) setPage(PDPage page)}.
 *
 * @param pageNumber The page for a remote destination.
 */
public void setPageNumber( int pageNumber )
```

Thus, replace

```
destination.setPageNumber(2);
```

by

```
destination.setPage(document.getPage(2));
```

Furthermore, you forgot to set a rectangle area for the link and you forgot to add the link to the page annotations.

All together:

```
PDPage page = document.getPage(1);

PDAnnotationLink link         = new PDAnnotationLink();
PDPageDestination destination = new PDPageFitWidthDestination();
PDActionGoTo action           = new PDActionGoTo();

destination.setPage(document.getPage(2));
action.setDestination(destination);
link.setAction(action);
link.setPage(page);

link.setRectangle(page.getMediaBox());
page.getAnnotations().add(link);
```

*([AddLink](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/annotate/AddLink.java#L40) test `testAddLinkToMwb_I_201711`)*

Comment: why do we need to do `link.setPage(page)` here?  Also, can you point me to right docs to understand more on `Annotations` of the page. I want to understand more on theoretical part of it.

Comment: @ScrapCode *"why do we need to do `link.setPage(page)` here?"* - If you mean why the argument has to be a `PDPage` page object and not an `int` page number: That's how PDF internal links are modelled in PDF objects: arrays in which the first entry is a reference to the page object and the following ones indicate where on that page the link goes. External links are modelled using arrays with a page number instead.

Comment: @ScrapCode *"Also, can you point me to right docs to understand more on Annotations of the page. I want to understand more on theoretical part of it."* - I'd recommend reading the PDF specification ISO 32000, in particular the parts on pages and on annotations. You can download a free copy by Adobe [here](http://www.adobe.com/go/pdfreference/). (The exact URL may be a moving target...)